# How to change width of individual QBarSet in a QStackedBarSeries?

Tags: c++, qt, qchart

I'm trying to create a [mosaic plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosaic_plot) series to include in a widget.

[QStackedBarSeries](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.7/qstackedbarseries.html#details) seems like the best place to start but I'm unable to change the width of individual bars in it. (please correct me if there is a better/simpler starting point!)

I digged through the [QBarSet](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qbarset.html#details) to see if I can subclass it to scale it's width but it appears that the graphing is done in the QStackedBarSeries.
Is my only option to subclass [QAbstractBarSeries](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.7/qabstractbarseries.html) to make the bar widths customizable?

Thanks!

Comment: Update in case this is useful to others: I was never able to find a way to update the widths of individual bars, I also explored qwt plots but no luck there either. Instead, I drew the plot entirely in a graphics scene.